# Change application settings for a deployed class library?

Tags: .net, asp.net, appsettings

If I define application level settings (using Properties.Settings) within a class library, can I change those settings once that dll is deployed to an app?  If so, how?  Do I just create the equivalent setting in web.config to override it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that you have to declare a section for the class library dll in the web.config.  So, if your namespace is "Company.Application.DataLayer" you would need to have a "Company.Application.DataLayer.Properties.Settings" section declared within your "applicationSettings" section.

Note: To have that section be recognized, you must also declare it within the applicationsettings sectionGroup of your web.config.